# Where to set include path for static code analyzer in Spyder

Tags: python, static-analysis, spyder

Using Spyder Python(3.4) IDE version 3.0.0 on Windows.

I've set custom include paths via the PYTHONPATH Manager, but upon execution of the static code checker, I'll get "Unable to import [...]" error messages and further errors based on the missing imports.

How to make the static checker follow my custom paths?

Answer (score 1):

Include a empty `__init__.py` in your custom path or modules folder. This enables the [spyder static analysis](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/pylint.html#static-code-analysis) to index your **custom path**

although `__init__.py` is not required in [Python 3.3+](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/),
it's purely a **optional workaround**